# IOPS on EBS attached to EC2: Grafana vs AWS CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, provisioned-iops

I am troubleshooting an issue instead of Ops doing it, and for that, I needed to collect the IOPS happening in EBS which is attached to the EC2 instance.

I have both AWS cloudWatch and Grafana Dashboard, sharing below:

**AWS cloudWatch:**

[image]

**Grafana Dashboard:**

[image]

I am not able to understand which one is accurate? If I understand correctly, Grafana shows a very peak IOPS, whereas Cloudwatch shows fewer operations.

It's worth mentioning, that on average, logs (which are stored in one of the mount points) are  to the tune of 32G, so how come, as per AWS cloudwatch it can be 4 Operations/second.

Does one read / write (to EBS) correspond to 1 IOPS?

Comment: I found one article useful for IOS calculation in AWS:https://onica.com/blog/managed-services/calculate-aws-ebs-volume-iops/

Comment: Your CloudWatch graph only shows an hour of data. Set the time range to a day and it should be closer to the Grafana dashboard. If not, please update your question with the new graph.

Comment: You should also switch from "Sum" to "Average" to be graphic the same thing.